# Non text response data received in Jmeter sampler response

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

When I running Jmeter in non gui mode Im getting response error in Jmeter
[image: Error sampler response]

Im using below mentioned settings in the simple data writer in the script
[image: Simple data writer config]

I want to know whether server under test has thrown this Non-text response data error or error is something else and Jmeter is not able to interpret it so it is showing that.
Can someone help me understand this.
Thank you!!!

Comment: Hi Vaibhav, are you receiving this response for every request in the test plan.

Comment: Hi Zohair, no only for the failed requests. I have marked data writer to only capture on error. Suppose if I get total 80 failed requests then out of those 80 for 50to60 requests i get this error.

Answer (score 0):

This error will occur when [SampleResult.getDataType()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getDataType--) function returns anything other than `text`

You can try writing the response data using [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) and some custom [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy), for instance:

```
if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
    new File('response.bin').bytes = prev.getResponseData()
}
```

you can amend this `response.bin` filename to include the current thread number, iteration, name of the sampler and so on